# Reading a resource in a war file which is not under classes dir

Tags: java, war

I am having a web application having following structure:

```
WEB-INF
 |-classes
    -- This is empty
 |-templates
         |-abc.properties
         |- xyz.properties    
 |-lib
     |-internal.jar (all classes of our application)
     |- other jars
```

These are bundled as a war

I want to read properties in the the files present in WEB-INF/templates.
NOTE: Above operation needs to be done from one of the class present in internal.jar. Basically they are on classpath

I tried following to get the resources but it is not able to search it.
{code}
1.

```
final InputStream inputStream = FileTemplateDaoImpl.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(resourcePath)
{/code}
where i tried following as resource path:
 templates/abc.properties
 /WEB-INF/templates/abc.properties
```

Comment: what is the AS that u are using?

Comment: Which server are you using? eg: tomcat, jboss, ...

Comment: I am using jetty server

Answer (score 0):

I presume here that once you open the war file these *.properties files are available under `WEB-INF/templates`, now the class which is trying to utilize these property files, try below mentioned code block.

```
ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
InputStream is = classLoader.getResourceAsStream("WEB-INF/templates/abc.properties");
```

Comment: This is not working. I guess ServletContext is required to get the webapp private resources. I am doing it in a normal class, may I need to get the servlet context somehow.